# How to automatically get new mails from gmail account using java?

Tags: java, email, gmail

I know my question is more likely to be discussed rather than really answered (because it's very large), but I need some elements and "advices" to really get started, sorry for that.

So I've got a java program which has to analyse some URLs, I've finished this part. For the moment, the user has to enter manually the link into my program, then the link is analysed.

Now I have to retrieve automatically those links, which will be sent to me via e-mail. (In a special Gmail inbox created for that purpose)

So I need to :

- Let my Java program "listen" to my inbox
- Extract the link of any new mail in order to analyse it

There are many problems, according to the way I choose to access to my inbox (POP3, GMail API...), according to the frequency my application would check the inbox, maybe there would be authentification problems...  Even how to let my application run as a "daemon"...

And I really don't know how to get started, which choices to make etc.

Any help is welcome of course, if you have any documentation or else. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [IMAP access](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en).

Comment: Use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/), and check inbox every few minuites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several ways of doing this.

I suggest you using Java Mail, that has a simple and useful API.

You have some documentation and examples in this URL:

https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples

Look at the class `monitor` (very bad name!!!) inside the examples. This class monitor a mail box for new emails.

Comment: Thank you ! :) I'll test that class. I just need a precision, in the program there is : `Usage: monitor <host> <user> <password> <mbox> <freq>` What is the "host" ?

Comment: For gmail, the host is `imap.gmail.com`, and I also had to add this line right after creating the object props : `props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");` and that works well ! Thank you very much for showing me that `monitor` class ! :)

Comment: @Malik if you think my answer is what you're looking for, please check the answer as the chosen one

Comment: Sorry I forgot to select it. ^^